# Does time resolution affect daily quota in Google Health API?

Tags: google-api, google-trends, google-healthcare-api

I am using Google Health API to download trends for several search terms for all countries around the world, for multiple years. As I am searching for quite a few terms, I frequently reach the daily quota. Right now, I am downloading weekly data.

My question is, if I change the time resolution from weeks to months or years, will I be able to get data for more terms/countries, before I reach the quota? In other words, is the quota counted by data point or by request?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/quotas

Comment: I read this page and couldn't find an answer to my question.